# Animate element from left to right with specific transition

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-animate

I have an element that I want to have behavior similar to this:

[image]

Maybe it's easier to use this gif, but my goal is to make it through script (or css), so I want to animate the "cube" with similar behavior like the gif.
So far I achieve moving the "cube" from left to right, but I can't find solution where I can slow the "cube" when is near the center, and speed up when is moving away from the center.

**HTML:**

```
 <div class="holder">
   <div class="cube">
   </div>
 </div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.holder{
    position:relative;
    width:400px;
}
.cube{
   position:absolute; display:none;background: #48a548; 
   width: 10px; height: 10px; 
}
```

**Jquery:**

```
var width = $(".holder").width(); 

setInterval(function () {
 $(".cube").fadeIn("fast").css({ left: "0%" }).animate(
  { 
    left: "100%" 
  }, 
  width).fadeOut("slow");
}, 2500);
```

---

**[JSFIDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/98cnauuj/)**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the animation with the correct easing and using only css (better performances).

```css
@-webkit-keyframes loader {
 0% { left: 0%; }
 100% { left: 100%; }
}
@keyframes loader {
 0% { left: 0%; }
 100% { left: 100%; }
}

.holder {
 position:relative;
 width:400px;
 height: 10px;
}
.cube {
 position: absolute;
 width: 10px;
 height: 10px;
 left: 0;
 background-color: #48a548;
 -webkit-animation: loader 3s cubic-bezier(0.030, 0.615, 0.995, 0.415) infinite;
 animation: loader 3s cubic-bezier(0.030, 0.615, 0.995, 0.415) infinite;
}
.cube:nth-of-type(1) {
 -webkit-animation-delay: 0.2s;
 animation-delay: 0.2s;
}
.cube:nth-of-type(2) {
 -webkit-animation-delay: 0.40s;
 animation-delay: 0.40s;
}
.cube:nth-of-type(3) {
 -webkit-animation-delay: 0.6s;
 animation-delay: 0.6s;
}
.cube:nth-of-type(4) {
 -webkit-animation-delay: 0.8s;
 animation-delay: 0.8s;
}
.cube:nth-of-type(5) {
 -webkit-animation-delay: 1.0s;
 animation-delay: 1.0s;
}
```

```html
<div class="holder">
 <div class="cube"></div>
 <div class="cube"></div>
 <div class="cube"></div>
 <div class="cube"></div>
 <div class="cube"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use CSS Animations: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_animations.asp
Example: http://jsfiddle.net/98cnauuj/1/

```
.cube {
    -webkit-animation: cubeanim 1s infinite; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    animation: cubeanim 1s infinite;
}

/* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
@-webkit-keyframes cubeanim {
    0% {
     left: 0;   
    }

    20% {
     left: 40%;   
    }
    80% {
     left: 60%;   
    }
    100% {
     left: 100%;   
    }
}

/* Standard syntax */
@keyframes cubeanim {
    0% {
     left: 0;   
    }

    20% {
     left: 40%;   
    }
    80% {
     left: 60%;   
    }
    100% {
     left: 100%;   
    }
}
```

(Of course you need to adjust the values to make it look good, it's just to show you a basic implementation)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var width = $(".holder").width();
setInterval(function () {
    $(".cube").fadeIn("fast").css({
        left: "0%"
    }).animate({
        left: "+=50%"
    }).animate({
        left: "+=5%"
    }, width).animate({
        left: "+=45%"
    }).fadeOut("fast");
}, 2500);
```

[**FIDDLE.**](http://jsfiddle.net/98cnauuj/2/)